# Nifi: how to handle file attributes in groovy

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I  have   to  write several  attribute  in case  certain conditions   will  be  fullfiled, but  if    only  'else'  clause should   be  fullfiled (  in case  count  and  fault  both are  null  )  i can't  make   options  write  in  else   block ,  what  hsould  i  change  ,  here is  my  code

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
def flowFile=session.get();
String attr=flowFile.getAttribute("count");
String fault=flowFile.getAttribute("error");
if(attr=="0"){
flowFile=session.putAttribute(flowFile,"empty","empty");
}
else  if(fault!=" "){
log.error(fault.toString());
}
else {
flowFile=session.putAttribute(flowFile,"good","good");
}
session.transfer(flowFile,REL_SUCCESS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a space in your fault check, I think you want an empty string there. In Groovy you can just check the "truthiness" of fault, you don't have to see if it is empty or null:

```
if(fault) {
  log.error(fault.toString())
}
```